# Правильное присвоение переменной пустого значения

Tags: c#, строки

Есть ли разница в присвоении переменной пустого значения такими способами?

```
String s = null; 
String s;
```

Comment: В разных языках разные правила относительно дефолтных значений. Добавьте тэг языка чтобы вам быстрее ответили.

Comment: на самом деле строки делают разные вещи: первая явно инициализирует значением, вторая просто объявляет переменную

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если это объявление локальных переменных, разница есть.

Первая переменная инициализирована значением `null`.
Вторая переменная не инициализирована.

Поэтому вы можете читать значение из первой переменной и передавать её значение в функцию. А во вторую переменную вы можете только писать, читать из неё вы можете только после записи в неё. И передавать вторую переменную в функцию можно только как `out`-параметр.

---

А если это объявление полей класса, разницы нет. Поля класса, у которых нет явно прописанной программистом инициализации, инициализируются* значением по умолчанию, которое для типа `System.String` есть `null`.

---

*Если в конструкторе присваивается другое значение, компилятор имеет право выкинуть присвоение `null`, если докажет, что никто [с однопоточной точки зрения] не сможет увидеть этот самый `null`. (*Это было примечание для формалистов.*)